# Custom dialog box HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I am fairly new to web development and am working on a personal project. As part of the project I am trying to learn how to create custom dialog and where possible make use of existing libraries to achieve what I want.

I came across alertify which pretty much covers the types of dialog box I want but there is one that I cant figure out how to create. The dialog box contains icons and I am not sure how I can achieve it. I have provided a screenshot of what I would like to achieve along with what I have done so far.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
if(!alertify.myAlert){
        //define a new dialog
        alertify.dialog('myAlert',function factory(){
          return{
            main:function(message){
              this.message = message;
              this.body = '<h1> test <h1>'
            },
            setup:function(){
                return { 
                  buttons:[{text: "Close", key:27/*Esc*/}],
                  focus: { element:0 }
                };
            },
            prepare:function(){
              this.setContent(this.message);
              this.body = '<h1> test <h1>'
            }
        }});
      }
      //launch it.
      alertify.myAlert("Type in your message below and choose how you would like to share!");
```

I have used this guide - https://alertifyjs.com/factory.html to create the above dialog box.

If its not possible to create what I want with alertifyJS please could you suggest alternative ways. I would, where possible like to avoid using HTML to create the custom dialog - unless it is totally unavoidable. If it can be done with alertifyJS, I would highly prefer that :)

Comment: Whether in the HTML itself or in the JavaScript, you will have to write the HTML that displays in the dialog. Those icons could be a font set (see iconic or similar) or they could be images. It depends on how you want to implement.

Comment: Well do you know how to get that look in HTML first? That would be the first step....

Comment: @daddygames thanks for reply, so html is a must - please could you suggest how I can go about it?

Comment: @epascarello thanks for reply, I am fairly new, at my current position I can do basic HTML and walk through tutorials to do some of the complex ones as well. but I have searched around and couldnt find anything quite similar to what I want and therefore am unable to alter them to suit my needs

Comment: However, I am still searching as doing this post but wanted to boost my research with help people who know more then me. So  I can move onto some of the more advanced features within my project

Comment: from the documentation on the alertifyjs website, it appears that in the build:function() you set this.body = '<h1>whatever html you want</h1>'; Please attempt to write the HTML and post it here if you are not getting what you want from it. We will help from there.

Comment: Hi, I am following what you suggest and first i am testing a small code by entering this.body = '<h1> test <h1>' but it doesnt seem to appear on the dialog box. Please see updated post.